# Event listener in HTML vs. addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener

I want to add an event listener to an HTML element which replaces the default behavior by custom behavior. I know two different ways of adding event listeners: (1) use the JavaScript function `addEventListener` to add an event to a DOM element:

```
<form class="my-form">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll(".my-form").forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener("submit", doSomething);
  });
  function doSomething(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Data received");
  }
</script>
```

(2) use the HTML attributes `on*`:

```
<form onsubmit="doSomething()">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
  function doSomething(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Data received");
  }
</script>
```

However, the first one does what it should do, the second one doesn't. The second code still uses the default submit handler. So, I'm wondering whether the behavior of the first example can be achieved with HTML attributes. And besides, I would like to know which way of adding event handlers is generally preferred.

Comment: The event object doesn't get passed to inline event listeners. Thus you cannot call e.preventDefault in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first version  - but dont use querySelectorAll if you only have one form. If you have only one form, give it an ID and use document.getElementById instead.

If you have many, I would delegate:

```
<div id="formContainer">
  <form class="my-form">
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
  <form class="my-form">
    <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("formContainer").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Data received");
  });

</script>
```

To do the second, we used to do this in the previous millenium

```
<form onsubmit="return doSomething()">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<script>
  function doSomething() {
    console.log("Data received");
    return false
  }
</script>
```

but it is not recommended

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some time ago, I think I have read that one should prefer using CSS selectors over IDs. Apart from probably performance benefits, does `document.getElementById` has more to offer?

Comment: It makes more sense. It tells us you have ONE specific element on the page. If you use a forEach on a querySelectorAll, it will work on one OR multiple elements but I would also EXPECT multiple elements if I read it. And yes, it is faster to use getElementById

Answer (score 3):

In the second case you're calling `doSomething()` with no argument, so `e` will be `undefined`. You need to pass the event as an argument explicitly:

```
<form onsubmit="doSomething(event)">
```

Comment: So, `event` is a valid variable inside the `onsubmit` attribute?

Comment: Yes. You can use `event` and `this`.

Comment: I see. Thank you.